# Rationale to use \input{filename} on the pdflatex command line?

Tags: best-practices, input

In a tex.SX [user profile](https://tex.stackexchange.com/users/19356/garbage-collector), I read the best practice recommendation

> Execute `pdflatex \input{filename}` instead of `pdflatex filename`.

I have always used the latter one, directly, in scripts, and in Makefiles.

What would be a reason to *always* use `pdflatex \input{filename}` instead?

Comment: you can ask Garbage Collector aka Adorable Creature herself [in the chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/41/tex-latex-and-friends), she is there from time to time.

Comment: Oh, I totally missed that I already have the "talk in chat" privilege now.

Comment: Chatting requires "only" 20 pts :)

Comment: It should be meant as best typing practice. :-)

Comment: @GarbageCollector Turning a disadvantage to an advantage, clever! :-)

Comment: @HeikoOberdiek: :-)

Comment: [a good comment from math.se site](http://chat.stackexchange.com/transcript/message/8707431#8707431)

Answer (score 23, accepted):

### Advantages

- It is a good trick, if someone wants to put TeX code before. Examples:

  ```
  pdflatex '\def\foo{bar}\input{filename}'
  pdflatex '\includeonly{introduction}\input{filename}'
  ```

  or inside `\write18` (shell escape feature):

  ```
  \immediate\write18{\detokenize{pdflatex '\def\foo{bar}\input{filename}'}}
  \immediate\write18{\detokenize{pdflatex '\includeonly{introduction}\input{filename}'}}
  ```

  e-TeX's `\detokenize` prevents the expansion of the macros inside `\write`, see [question](https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/97958/16967).
- Also LaTeX catches the error message a little better, because it checks for the file first and throws a proper error message.

  The TeX behaviour of '\input' without braces or on the command line would be:

  ```
  pdflatex filename

  ! I can't find file `filename'.
  <*> filename

  (Press Enter to retry, or Control-D to exit)
  Please type another input file name:
  ```

  Then you can escape from there with `Control-D` (Unix) or `Control-Z` (Windows).
  or the file `x.tex` of LaTeX's [tools bundle](http://www.ctan.org/pkg/tools) can be used for this purpose.

  LaTeX throws instead:

  ```
  pdflatex '\input{filename}

  ! LaTeX Error: File `filename.tex' not found.

  Type X to quit or <RETURN> to proceed,
  or enter new name. (Default extension: tex)

  Enter file name:
  ```

  Then LaTeX already looks for `x`  or `X` as answer to abort the job.

  **Answer to a comment:** However, in both variants an error message is
  thrown, if the file does not exist. An interactive prompt in a
  command chain (`pdflatex test && do something`) can be avoided by
  the pdfTeX options `interaction=batchmode` or `--interaction=nonstopmode`.

### Disadvantages

- It's longer than `filename`.
- The backslash needs special treatment (quoting, doubling) with many shells.

### Summary

IMHO the two described "advantages" are indeed too weak for always using `pdflatex \input{test}` over `pdflatex test`. At least I have tried to find possible reasons. And the trick with putting TeX stuff before `\input` is worth to be remembered.

Comment: Still, these doesn't seem to me as advantages of `pdflatex "\input{filename}"`, rather as features: You can do `pdflatex "\def\foo{bar}\input{filename}"` if you have a need for such trick. It is a bit like saying: _You can use `cat` this way: `cat file | sed 's///g'` because this allows you to do `cat file | sed 's/foo/bar/g'` easily._

Comment: Well, saying `cat file | sed ...`, independently of what `sed` ends up doing, is a canonical example of a Useless Use Of Cat... :-)

Comment: I am sorry, but I still don't get it. I use the `\input` trick quite a lot to put TeX code before when I need so, but what exactly is the advantage of a _plain_ `pdflatex \input{filename}` over `pdflatex filename`, as asked by the OP?

Comment: I really should try asking the user who stated this in the first place. I see the point in the answer, but advantage #1 is not as common to make a habit of `\input{}`, and advantage #2 breaks `pdflatex file && do something` bash chains with an interactive prompt. I still see no reason to *always* use it.