# How to invoke \write18{pdflatex "\def\param{...}\input{filename}"}?

Tags: shell-escape

Why can't I compile the following even though I have enabled `-shell-escape`?

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{filecontents}
\begin{filecontents*}{inputfile.tex}
%\def\paramA{standalone}
\def\paramB{Hello World}
\documentclass{\paramA}
\begin{document}
\paramB
\end{document}
\end{filecontents*}

\begin{document}
\immediate\write18{pdflatex "\def\paramA{standalone}\input{inputfile}"}
\immediate\write18{inputfile.pdf}
done!
\end{document}
```

### Log File

```
This is pdfTeX, Version 3.1415926-2.4-1.40.13 (TeX Live 2012/W32TeX)
 \write18 enabled.

<< the unnecessary texts are intentionally removed by me for the sake of simplicity >>

No file executor.aux.
! Undefined control sequence.
<write> pdflatex "\def \paramA 
                               {standalone}\input {inputfile}"
l.13 ...\def\paramA{standalone}\input{inputfile}"}

?
```

Comment: As the error message says: `\paramA` is not defined. `\write18` tries to expand it before sending it to the shell (which it shouldn’t in this example). It needs therefore to be protected by `\noexpand` or `\string` or `\unexpanded`: `\immediate\write18{pdflatex "\def\noexpand\paramA{standalone}\noexpand\input{inputfile}"}` or `\immediate\write18{\unexpanded{pdflatex "\def\paramA{standalone}\input{inputfile}"}}`

Comment: Or `\immediate\write18{pdflatex "\def\string\paramA{standalone}\string\input{inputfile}"}` or `\immediate\write18{\detokenize{pdflatex "\def\paramA{standalone}\input{inputfile}"}}`. The error is caused by the expansion of `\immediate\write`.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

As the error message describes, the macro `\paramA` is undefined.

`\write18` tries to expand its content before forwarding it to the shell, so you need to “protect” (not `\protect`!) the macros `\paramA` and `\input` with

- `\noexpand` (single use),
- `\string` (single use),
- `\unexpanded` (multiple uses), or
- `\detokenize` (multiple uses).

The easiest solution in this case would be to use `\unexpanded` or `\detokenize` as you actually have no macros that needs to get expanded:

```
\immediate\write18{\unexpanded{pdflatex "\def\paramA{standalone}\input{inputfile}"}}
```

Single macros needs to be protected every time:

```
\immediate\write18{pdflatex "\def\string\paramA{standalone}\string\input{inputfile}"}
```