# Are there placeholder variables in LaTeX to be defined on compilation?

Tags: pdftex, compiling, templates

I am trying to create a template document in LaTeX, which contains text placeholders that I would define during compilation. For example:

```
\documentclass{article}

\begin{document}
\section{Introduction}

This is a placeholder document which contains [p1], [p2] and [p3].

\end{document}
```

So that I can later compile `latex mydoc.tex p1=First p2=Second p3=Third`

and get an output of `This is a placeholder document which contains First, Second and Third.`

I am wondering how can I achieve this (or some similar behavior)?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could use [Heiko's trick](https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/97160). Suppose your file is called `test.tex`. Then compiling

```
\documentclass{article}

\begin{document}
\section{Introduction}

This is a placeholder document which contains \PlaceHolder1, \PlaceHolder2 and \PlaceHolder3.

\end{document}
```

with

```
pdflatex '\def\PlaceHolder#1{\ifcase#1\or blub\or bla\or pft\fi}\input{test}'
```

yields

[image]

Or, a more fancy version: assume `placeholders.txt` contains

```
p1=First,p2=Second,p3=Third
```

and the TeX file

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{catchfile}
\usepackage{pgf}
\newcommand{\PlaceHolder}[1]{\pgfkeysvalueof{/placeholder/p#1}}
\CatchFileEdef{\PlaceHolderKeys}{placeholders.txt}{}
\edef\tmp{\noexpand\pgfkeys{/placeholder/.cd,p1/.initial={},p2/.initial={},p3/.initial={},%
\PlaceHolderKeys}}\tmp
\begin{document}
\section{Introduction}

This is a placeholder document which contains \PlaceHolder{1},
 \PlaceHolder{2} and \PlaceHolder{3}.

\end{document}
```

yields

[image]

Comment: Thank you! This is what I was looking for